# SQL error "Invald column name" on Umbraco upgrade

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I am attempting to upgrade Umbraco from 7.2.6 to 7.4.2

I've updated all the packages via NuGet but when I attempt to access the AuthorizeUpgrade URL and login to update the database, I get the following error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
Invalid column name 'securityStampToken',
Invalid column name 'lastLogindate'
```

As the database has not yet been updated, how can I access these 2 columns and why is the upgrade expecting them to be there when I login?

I've checked that the web.config has the correct membership values (the same as a clean install)

```
<membership defaultProvider="UmbracoMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="UmbracoMembershipProvider" type="Umbraco.Web.Security.Providers.MembersMembershipProvider, Umbraco" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" minRequiredPasswordLength="4" useLegacyEncoding="true" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" defaultMemberTypeAlias="Member" passwordFormat="Hashed" />
        <add name="UsersMembershipProvider" type="Umbraco.Web.Security.Providers.UsersMembershipProvider, Umbraco" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" minRequiredPasswordLength="4" useLegacyEncoding="true" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

Is there anything else I can check? What is expecting the columns to be there when I authorize the upgrade?

Thanks

Mike

Comment: It's quite likely there is an issue with your database - a scenario the dev team hasn't come across yet, and you may want to log a report on the Umbraco issue tracker.  When you do, they may ask you for a copy of your database so they can diagnose properly; and you can zip it up and upload it set to private so only you and the core team can view it.  Helped me a few times with upgrades

Comment: @RobertFoster same here, tried upgrading 6.2.5 to 7.4.2 got the same errors

Answer (score 1):

Try to open an incognito tab or clean all your cookies and try it again

Comment: This does no good. The issue is that the Upgrade Authorization code tries to authenticate against the database certain columns (securityStampToken, lastLoginDate) do not exist. Since you can't login, you can't update the database. And without the database getting upgraded, you can't login. I nice neat Catch 22.

Comment: Works for me. Thanks!